# How can I solve the error in zendframework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have got an error in zf3:

> Error
>           C:\xampp\htdocs\zf3\module\Application\view\application\index\contact.phtml:21
>           Message:
>           Call to a member function prepare() on string

```
<?php
    // within a view script
    $form = $this->form;
    //var_dump($form);

    $form->prepare();

    // Assuming the "contact/process" route exists...
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('process'));

    // Set the method attribute for the form
    $form->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    // Get the form label plugin
    $formLabel=$this->plugin ('formLabel');

    // Render the opening tag
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
    ?>
```

Comment: can you show your controller code, how you return "form" variable to view? the $this->form should be a Form instactance

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the controller action code but it is possible to say for sure that you are assigning the form property in the view model with a string instead of a Zend\Form instance.

Just check the "form" property within the returned view model.